# MATLAB: concatenate 3 matrices into 1 new matrix with certain rule

Tags: matlab, matrix

3 matrices named as `A`, `B` and `C`. Each matrix have random `M x N` dimension. However, the `N` (column number) are equal. Randomly generate 1 row from each of the matrix and put into new matrix (named as `Fdata`) one by one, and then randomly generate 1 row from the each of the matrix again but can not be repeated from the previous randomly row generation and put into `Fdata` one by one again..do this accordingly...if one of the matrix is randomly generated once for each row without repeating, then the rest of the row can be randomly repeated again until the maximum rows from one of the matrix.

If `A` is matrix of 5x5, `B` is a matrix of 2x5 and `C` is the matrix of 3x5, the `Fdata` will be a 15x5 matrix

example:

```
A = 
6 6 4 7 8
4 7 1 6 9
3 5 8 0 1
6 5 8 1 2
9 4 2 0 1

B = 
4 7 2 8 5
5 6 0 1 2

C = 
1 6 4 5 1
8 6 7 1 3
3 0 4 5 8
```

**The final data i wish to get is**

```
Fdata = 
4 7 1 6 9 %randomly from matrix A
5 6 0 1 2 %randomly from matrix B
1 6 4 5 1 %randomly from matrix c
6 6 4 7 8 %randomly from matrix A (but not repeated from previous randomly generated row)
4 7 2 8 5 %randomly from matrix B (but not repeated from previous randomly generated row)
3 0 4 5 8 %randomly from matrix C (but not repeated from previous randomly generated row)
3 5 8 0 1 %randomly from matrix A (but not repeated from previous randomly generated row)
4 7 2 8 5 %randomly from matrix B, repeated row because the row of matrix B is fully randomly generated
8 6 7 1 3 %randomly from matrix C (but not repeated from previous randomly generated row)
9 4 2 0 1 %randomly from matrix A (but not repeated from previous randomly generated row)
....
```

what code shall i write to get the `Fdata`?

---

2nd question:

let say `Fdata=xlsread('abc.xls,);` original `Fdata` has 5x2 matrix, after some codes, `Fdata` become 5x5 matrix..then `xlswrite('abc.xls',Fdata,'sheet2');` ..error occur...??? `Index exceeds matrix dimensions`...how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Quick working try, it can be optimized but then a few more details are needed: how many iterations are you doing ? is there a breaking condition ? Will you always use three matrices to feed Fdata ?

Here is a working sample of code:

```
function Fdata=buildFdata
A=rand(5,5);
B=rand(2,5);
C=rand(3,5);
selectedA=[];
selectedB=[];
selectedC=[];
n=max([size(A,1) size(B,1) size(C,1)]);
Fdata=zeros(3*n,5);
for i=1:3:3*n-2
    [Fdata,A,selectedA]=randomfeed(Fdata,A,selectedA,i);
    [Fdata,B,selectedB]=randomfeed(Fdata,B,selectedB,i+1);
    [Fdata,C,selectedC]=randomfeed(Fdata,C,selectedC,i+2);
end
end

function [Fdata,Mat,selectedMat]=randomfeed(Fdata,Mat,selectedMat,i)
if(~isempty(Mat))
    index=randline(size(Mat,1));
    Fdata(i,:)=Mat(index,:);
    selectedMat(end+1,:)=Mat(index,:);
    Mat(index,:)=[];
else
    index=randline(size(selectedMat,1));
    Fdata(i,:)=selectedMat(index,:);
end    
end

function n=randline(nlines)
if(nlines==1)
    n=1;
else
    n=randi(nlines-1)+1;
end
end
```

Comment: each Fdata there will always be feed by 3 different matrices...the iteration is depend on the maximum rows of either of the 3 matrices..from your code, the Fdata=zeros(10,5) should be Fdata=zeros(15,5)...the code got error..

Comment: I modified accordingly. Which error are you experiencing ? It works fine on my computer.

Comment: The code work well, however, if apply my data, the selected(A,B,C) got problem...??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch..Fdata(i,:)=A(index,:);

Comment: It is weird ... How are your data different from the random matrices used for this example ? If it is possible maybe you could provide your real data or a subset of it if too long.

Comment: i found out the reason..because the Fdata=zeros(3*n,5);..the column of my data not 5...thanks for your helpful..Aabaz..

Comment: let say Fdata=xlsread('abc.xls,); original Fdata has 5x2 matrix, after come codes, Fdata become 5x5 matrix..then xlswrite('abc.xls',Fdata,'sheet2');..error occur...??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions...how can i solve this problem?